# Converting youtube url to iframe embed code doesn't work correctly (preg_replace)

Tags: php, regex

I have problems to convert youtube urls to iframe embed code. It works correctly only if there is some text before youtube link and only with 1 video.

Code:

```
$search = '@[^"\'](?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=))([\w\-]{8,25})(?:[&\w-=%]*)\b@xsi';
$replace = '<iframe title="$1" class="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$message = preg_replace($search, $replace, $message);
```

**Example 1** - this is OK (everything in one line without line breaks)

Text:

```
text http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wDOjZvoRLQ text
```

Result:

```
text<iframe title="4wDOjZvoRLQ" class="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4wDOjZvoRLQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> text
```

**Example 2** - not OK. When I add line breaks to the text, the result for some reason contains unclosed `<br /` tag before `<iframe>`.

Text:

```
text
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wDOjZvoRLQ
text
```

Result:

```
text <br /<iframe title="4wDOjZvoRLQ" class="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4wDOjZvoRLQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> <br />text
```

**Example 3** - not OK. Only 2 youtube URLs without any text. The result for some reason contains "`http:/`" before `<iframe>`

Text:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wDOjZvoRLQ
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wDOjZvoRL
```

Result:

```
http:/<iframe title="4wDOjZvoRLQ" class="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4wDOjZvoRLQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> <br /<iframe title="4wDOjZvoRLQ" class="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4wDOjZvoRLQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$reg_exUrl_youtube = "/(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'> \r\n]+)(?![^<]*>)/";
$articleText = "text goes here"
  if ( preg_match($reg_exUrl_youtube, $articleText, $youtubeUrlData) ) {
    $articleText = preg_replace($reg_exUrl_youtube, "<div class=\"video-container\"><iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$youtubeUrlData[1]}\" allowFullScreen frameborder=\"0\"width=\"560\" height=\"315\"></iframe></div>", $articleText);
  }
```

Does that solve your problem? The $reg_exUrl_youtube will preg_match all youtube links within $articleText and replace them with the embed code and output the $articleText as before with all urls replaced.

This does not include youtube links found within a tag (e.g. `<a href="http://youtube.com">`) If you wish the pregmatch to do this change the regular expression to:

```
$reg_exUrl_youtube = "/(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'> \r\n]+)/";
```

Useful regular expression tester:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks. This works, but only with one video. If `$articleText` contains more than one Yutube URL, all `<iframes>` have the same video ID - all videos are the same.

Comment: Any ideas what do I need to change so that it wirks with multiple Youtube URLs?